# PWA notifications without backend

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-notifications

I am making a todo app with Javascript (PWA). There will be reminders for the todos. I want to send notifications to the user to remind them. Tasks and remind time will be stored in localStorage.

So now I want to send notifications without any backend. I have tried some tutorials, they all require a backend or Google push services for it.
Is there any way to send notifications without them?
I think the serviceWorker will have to keep running in the background and get the current time. Remind the user if current time and remind time matches.
So how to do it?